# Using two embedded fonts on one string

Tags: apache-flex, fonts

I would like to know how to use two embedded fonts in Flex in tag `<mx:Text>`
I am dynamically loading RSS description into it and would like to have the first character and characters unsupported by other font be in that first font. I limited the range of characters of that second font so all unsupported chars and first char should be in that first font.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by applying 2 different [TextFormat](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/text/TextFormat.html) objects to the text. Also see [setTextFormat()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat()) on the TextField class that allows you to specify a begin- and endIndex of the text range on which you want to set the textformat.